# Mac OS X quick user switch in iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiview, ios4

I want to flip a view like the Mac OS X user switch,i have used this code

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.75];
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight forView:myview cache:YES];
[myview removeFromSuperview];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

But this flipping is different from mac os user switch, help me if you can..This code provides different flip.

Comment: please explain better what you need

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no built-in "cube rotate" in iOS. You'd need to create it yourself. There are several ways to do this. One way to approach it is to put both views into a single superview, and apply a CATransform3D transform to the "target" view to create the box. Then animate a CATransform3D for the entire superview to rotate it. When you're done, remove the old "source" view.

See the [Core Animation Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Articles/Layers.html), particularly Transforming a Layer's Geometry, for more information.